# Record not inserted while using @ManyToOne mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 tables 'orders' and 'orderlines' and used bidirectional OneToMany mapping.When i save the order, record is successfully inserted into table 'orders'.But my 'orderlines' table is empty.No record is inserted.

This is the save operation code in Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ordersuccess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processOrder(@ModelAttribute("order") Order order, 
            @ModelAttribute("cart") Cart cart,
            BindingResult result) {

        if (!result.hasErrors()) {          
            Set<OrderLine> orderLines = new HashSet<OrderLine>();
            for(CartLine c : cart.getCartLines()) {
                OrderLine line = new OrderLine();
                line.setOrder(order);
                line.setProduct(c.getProduct());
                line.setProductPrice(c.getProduct().getPrice());
                line.setTotalPrice(c.getPrice());
                orderLines.add(line);
                order.setOrderLines(orderLines);
            }
                orderService.save(order);
                orderLineService.save(orderLine);
        }
        return "ordersuccess";
    }
```

Can someone point me what wrong i am doing.

**EDIT:
OrderLine.java**

```
public class OrderLine {
     @Id    
     @GeneratedValue  
        @Column(name="orderline_id") 
        private int orderline_id;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Product.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name="products",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_id")
                )
    private Product product;

)
```

**Order.java**

```
public class Order {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="id")
        private int id;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
        private Set<OrderLine> orderLines;
    //getter/setter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orderLines object is created:

```
Set<OrderLine> orderLines = new HashSet<OrderLine>();
```

You then add lines to it:

```
orderLines.add(line);
```

But it never attributed to an order or sent to the service layer.

Also the OrderLine.product mapping should be like this

```
public class OrderLine {
    @Id    
    @GeneratedValue  
    @Column(name="orderline_id") 
    private int orderline_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

}
```

and Order.orderLines should have a cascade:

```
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<OrderLine> orderLines;

}
```

You then need to save the orderLines:

```
order.setOrderLines(orderLines);
```

and save the order:

```
orderService.save(order);
```

When order is saved it will cascade the orderlines and the associated product too.

If you have bidirectional associations don't forget to set both sides.

Comment: should i also save orderline ?

Comment: If you have a bidirectional association you must have both sides in-sync.

Comment: I created DAO and service classes and tried to save orderline, but it throws SQLException: Field 'product_id' doesn't have a default value
. How can i set product_id? It is already auto increment only.Please see my edit.

Comment: I need Order and Product classes as well as the orderService.save code and any DAO it mat call, to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Now its working. I guessed i was doing wrong in the controller code for save.But i am wrong in the entity classes mapping.